# Sub Queries

Tags: database

How do you represent the sub queries in SELECT and WHERE clauses?

Answer (score 9):

Statements that include subqueries usually take one of these formats:

- WHERE expression [NOT] IN (subquery)
- WHERE expression comparison_operator [ANY | ALL] (subquery)
- WHERE [NOT] EXISTS (subquery)

[Subquery Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx) *(SQL Server 2008 Books Online, January 2009)*

Comment: Please note that many sub-queries are better represented as a join to a derived table (although the optimiser is getting better at translating them).

Answer (score 3):

You can use subqueries in SELECT and WHERE clauses like this:

```
select
  c.customerid,
  (
    select sum(i.amount) as totalspent
    from item i
    where i.customerid = c.customerid
  ) as totalspent
from customer c
where exists
(
  select *
  from purchase p
  where p.customerid = c.customerid
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten some good anwsers, but try to see if you can change your logic such that the sub-query takes place in the from clause, so that it is only run once instead of once for each row returned by the main query.

Sub-queries really suck the performance out of a system.

Comment: Agreed. Subqueries should be used sparingly.

Comment: True, many things you can do with subqueries you could also do with joins - with the EXPLAIN command you can then see which is faster.